# Issue with port forwarding on a Verizon G3100 router

Tags: port-forwarding, webserver, wamp

## Port Forwarding Situation

For the past couple of days, I have been trying to forward port 80 on my router to my web server, which can be located at “192.168.1.159”. However, I am unable to complete this task. Over the LAN, I can access the server by typing “192.168.1.159:80” in the search bar, and I can also do “localhost:80” and access the web server without problems.

[image]

Checklist

1. localhost:80 ✔️
2. 192.168.1.159:80 ✔️
3. [external IP]:80 ❌

Am I setting up the ports incorrectly? Is this a router issue?